# Testing my GCP Cloud function gives errors

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to GCP and deploxed my first test-function:

```
def easy(i):
   j = int(i) + 1
return j
```

As you can see I just want to get in touch with cloud functions. Google offers the possibility to test the cloud function by passing a json to the function. But unfortunately I can't get this to work.

Here's my query:

```
{"i":"3"}
```

[image]

That's the error from the log:

```
2021-03-21T12:28:09.540Zeasym213o6k2ngr7 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 87, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 2, in easy j = int(i) + 1 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Request'
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 87, in view_func return function(request._get_current_object()) File "/workspace/main.py", line 2, in easy j = int(i) + 1 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Request'
```

I quite experienced in python but I can't figure out what is wrong. Any ideas?

Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your post, the error in the log says:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Request'
```

which means, that the argument `i` is of the type `Request`...

If I look into the documentation guide [Writing Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#functions-writing-helloworld-http-python) I can see some examples of how the cloud function "signature" might look like:

```
def hello_http(request):
```

or

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
```

I would suggest to check how the cloud function is to be defined in your case, and follow the proposed pattern.